# how to skip windows service installation from setup project?

Tags: windows-installer

I have a setup installer using Visual Studio 2015, which is working fine on the normal scenario.

But due to my scenarios I had to add a Windows service in my project, but I want this service to be installed only at one place since it's a communication service between govt. website. While this setup has to be installed in all the User PC but my service should be skipped, except server.

How can I handle this part into the custom action of the Setup project?

Comment: You are using the wrong installer builder utility.  Creating a custom dialog that lets the user select the components to install is possible with more advanced ones, the kind that tend to cost money.  A very simple workaround is to just create two installers.

Comment: Thanks Hans,for your reply.

Comment: Second approach was already there in my mind from the beginning but the only thing is I want to Reduce the no of utilities to be installed by implementation team.Could you please suggest me any good Installer utility which will serve my purpose of choosing the components during installation.

Comment: Choose a tool that uses Features, they are the standard way to chose what functionality to install http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/authoring.htm